# Variables inside href don't work as intended

Tags: php, html

I created a function in wich i create a Table.
The function itself runs fine, but i want an link to another Page.
Inside that Page I work with GET Variables, so they need to go inside the URL.
I got:

```
$calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><a href="http://localhost/PHPOrdner/Calendar/Day.php?inputmonth='$inputMonth'&inputyear='$inputYear'&day='$list_day'"></a>'.$list_day.'</div>';
```

But that isn't working:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$inputMonth' (T_VARIABLE)
>   in...

I tried to escape the ' like: `.../Day.php?inputmonth=\'$inputMonth\'...`

But that gives me ".../Day.php?inputmonth=%27$inputMonth%27..." in my URL so the Code, where i need the variables doesn't work.

Using `<?php echo "..."; ?>` also doesn't work.
I'm still new to this, are there any other ways?

Comment: You cannot just put a variable next to a string, you to [concatenate](//stackoverflow.com/questions/11441369/php-string-concatenation) them.

Comment: Don't be `miser` add more `.` dots to concatenate string.

Comment: I didn't knew the reason was the String concatenation, otherwise i would not have asked. I'm sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string concatenation is wrong you forgot the `.`

Try:

```
$calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><a href="http://localhost/PHPOrdner/Calendar/Day.php?inputmonth='.$inputMonth.'&inputyear='.$inputYear.'&day='.$list_day.'></a>'.$list_day.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You lack `.`

```
$calendar = '<div class="day-number"><a href="http://localhost/PHPOrdner/Calendar/Day.php?inputmonth='.$inputMonth.'&inputyear='.$inputYear.'&day='.$list_day.'"></a>'.$list_day.'</div>';
```